# Github Page url not being github.io/repo/about but github.io/about instead

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Recently I tried deploying my portfolio web made from React to `github` pages with the url `user.github.io/portfolio-web` but when it got deploy, my pages (`/contact` or `/about`) got defaulted into `usesr.github.io/about`.

What I have right now is:
`user.github.io/about`

What I want is:
`user.github.io/portfolio-web/about`

Sample of my React code:

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<AboutMe />} />
  <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

In the package.json I already add the `"homepage": "https://user.github.io/portfolio-web",`

I tried reading the documentation and searching stack overflow but I don't know which keyword I should use for this search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have installed gh-pages:

```
npm install gh-pages
```

You need to have something similar in your package.json, right?

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
  "predeploy": "npm run build"
},
```

This script will build your React app and then deploy it to the GitHub Pages repository.

As you want to make changes to the routes in your React project, you will need to deploy:

```
npm run deploy
```

This will create a gh-pages branch in your GitHub repository with the necessary files to serve your app from the desired subdirectory path.

Oh, and I forgot the most important thing... have you configured your project in Github as gh-pages? If not, go to your GitHub repository settings, scroll down to the GitHub Pages section, and ensure that the branch is set to gh-pages.

If you have any further issues or questions, please let me know.

Comment: Yes I got the gh-pages, but I still don't have the url for the io/portfolio-web/about.
This is my portfolio website: https://tatpolc.github.io/portfolio-web/
When I press home it just goes back to: https://tatpolc.github.io/ where I want it to go to https://tatpolc.github.io/portfolio-web/

Comment: Have you checked the href path of the button? Because everything else is fine

Comment: Not sure where to check that, would you mind checking my git repo?
https://github.com/Tatpolc/portfolio-web

Comment: Okay, I think that the problem is related with the BrowserRouter... Modify this line in your App.js: <BrowserRouter basename="/portfolio-web"> Once you made the change, deploy your app

Comment: Wow! How cool!!! I'm so glad it helped you!